# Not able to populate AWS Glue ETL Job metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, metrics, aws-glue

I am trying to populate maximum possible Glue job metrics for some testing, below is the setup I have created:

- A crawler reads data (dummy customer data of 500 rows) from a CSV file placed in an S3 bucket.
- Used another crawler to crawl tables created in Redshift cluster.
- An ETL job finally reads data from csv file in s3 and dumps it into a Redshift table.

The job is running without any issue and i am able to see final data getting dumped into Redshift table, however, in the end, only below 5 Cloudwatch metrics are being populated:

- glue.jvm.heap.usage
- glue.jvm.heap.used
- glue.s3.filesystem.read_bytes
- glue.s3.filesystem.write_bytes
- glue.system.cpuSystemLoad

There are approximately 20 more metrics which are not getting populated.

Any suggestions on how to populate those remaining metrics as well?

Answer (score 1):

- Double check if the CW metrics for your job is enabled
- Make sure your job runs longer say > 3mins such that it allows CW to push the metrics

  - For this you can add a sleep time in your code
- Assuming that you are using Glue version 2.0+ for the above job, [please be advised that AWS Glue version 2.0+ does not use dynamic allocation, hence the ExecutorAllocationManager metrics are not available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/reduced-start-times-spark-etl-jobs.html#reduced-start-times-limitations). Trackback on using Glue 1.0 and you should confirm that all the documented metrics are now available.

Answer (score 0):

Met the same issue. Does your glue.s3.filesystem.read_bytes and glue.s3.filesystem.write_bytes have any data?

One possible reason is that the AWS Glue job metrics not emitted if job completes in less then 30 sec

Answer (score 0):

While running the job enable the metrics option under monitoring tab.